# ios swift 4 Google Maps - How do I remove the fade in/fade out animation on a GMS Marker while dragging?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to achieve an affect on ios that was pretty easy to do in android.  In android, Google Map markers have a visibility attribute (boolean) so it was easy, but the closest thing I've found in the ios SDK is the opacity field.

Whenever I set my opacity to zero, there's a fade out affect that isn't what I want.

Is there anyway to simply remove the fade animation on a Marker?

Thank you for any insights

-T

Answer (score 0):

Try use the animation keypath layer, it's work for me

```
CATransaction.begin()
let markerLayer = marker.layer
let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
fadeOutAnimation.keyPath = "opacity"
fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = 1
fadeOutAnimation.toValue = 0
fadeOutAnimation.duration = 0.35
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
    marker.map = nil
}
markerLayer.add(fadeOutAnimation, forKey: "fade")
CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate (or not) a `GMSMarker` you need to control its `tracksViewChanges` property:

> Controls whether the icon for this marker should be redrawn every
>   frame. 
>   Note that when this changes from NO to YES, the icon is
>   guaranteed to be redrawn next frame.
>
> Defaults to YES.

Once you create an instance of `GMSMarker` first, set its `tracksViewChanges` to `false` - should solve your issue since the `iconView` property won't get redrawn again

Also, you can animate its `iconView` property by:

- Set its `tracksViewChanges` to `true`
- Use the `iconView` reference to animate whatever you need
- When you're done, set its `tracksViewChanges` to `false`